# Puppeteer Query Selectors - how to get second match

Tags: javascript, node.js, css-selectors, puppeteer

```html
<table><tr><td>firstContent</td><td>secondContent</td></tr></table>
```

Querying this table with puppeteer's `page.$eval` I retrieve `firstContent`. How would I retrieve `secondContent`?

```js
const value = await page.$eval('table tr td', el => { return el.innerHTML });
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) like this:

```js
const value = await page.$eval('table tr td:nth-child(2)', el => { return el.innerHTML });
```

For more complex expressions, you could also make use of the `document.querySelectorAll` function within the [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) and then choose the second element like this:

```js
const value = await page.evaluate(
    () => document.querySelectorAll('table tr td')[1].innerHTML
);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`page.$eval`](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) runs `document.querySelector` within the page and return the first match to the selector if you want to access other elements matching your selector use [`page.$$eval`](https://devdocs.io/puppeteer/index#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) which runs `document.querySelectorAll` and returns an array of all matched elements.

An example case to retrieve the second element would be:

```
const second_value = await page.$$eval('table tr td', el => el[1].innerHTML);
```

Comment: el => el[1] (0) //  el=> return el[1] (x)

Comment: @BS100 that's right, the return qualifier is not needed